# Is it necessary to use null two times at the end of the code?

Tags: javascript, null

I have one question. Help me, please.

I have code in my teaching proggram:

```
alert(user.address ? user.address.street ? user.address.street.name : null : null);
```

But I can't understand, why he used "null" two times at the end of the code?

I understand that if `user.adress` - exist, then check whether `user.address.street` exist, if `user.address.street` - exist, then check whether `user.address.street.name exist`, if not alert - `null`.

But why did he write second `null`?

Comment: If the `user.address` was falsy, alert `null`. This is the `else branch` for the first `if`. You should not use nested ternary operators because it is very hard to read them correctly (Some argue you shouldn't use the ternary operator at all). A tranformation to `if` should give you an idea what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ? operator is a shorthand for an if-else assignment.

```
alert(user.address ? user.address.street ? user.address.street.name : null : null);
```

Is the short form for:

```
let res;
if (user.address) {
    if (user.address.street) {
          res = user.address.street.name;
    } else {
          res = null;
    }
} else {
    res = null;
}
alert(res);
```

In javascript there is also the 'optional chaining operator' which is probably what you want:

```
alert(user?.address?.name);
```

Which only access the objects properties if they are not null, otherwise returns null.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Now I understood. I learned next lesson. And now I know that it's more correctly to use this form alert(user?.address?.name);

Answer (score 0):

here
user.address ?
is condition sentence that have two operand. the first one is whole

```
user.address.street ? user.address.street.name : null
```

If the condition is true we'll go deeply to this sentence that is a condition sentence by own and have two operand again: first one is `user.address.street.name` (if nested condition is `true`) and the second one is `null` (if the nested condition is `false`).
the last null is the second operand of `user.address ?` if it's `false`.

Comment: Give a code snippet that solves the problem if possible.

Comment: @Hritik Sharma
if we write  our code like the question above is, yes its needed to arrive our goal. but there is optional chaining to make it easy .it's like: alert(user?.address?.name);